# Lenovo laptop BSODs at semi-random times

Tags: windows, bsod, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo laptop is 2 years old so it is right at the point where I can't decide if this is a hardware failure or not.

I've managed to trigger BSODs in various conditions, resulting in IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (most common), MEMORY_MANAGEMENT, or BAD_POOL_HEADER (less common).

I haven't pinpointed the exact causes yet but these are what I've noticed tend to trigger BSODs:

Moving the laptop while in use (not necessarily a jolt, slight shuffling causes BSODs too) (most common cause)

Using the laptop in warm conditions

Moving the battery

So far I've tried a system refresh, total drivers and Windows Updates update run, and upgrading to Windows 10, but the problem has still persisted.

The Minidump and other debug files are here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=33847DD02D83E981!400&authkey=!APOXx1UfGagY5y8&ithint=folder%2c

Note: the computer froze while collecting the Minidump files during the BSOD so they may be incomplete.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Moving the laptop while in use (not necessarily a jolt, slight shuffling causes BSODs too) (most common cause)* sounds like a hardware problem.

Unreliable memory tends to result in BSODs. Run a memtest86 (which is a part of almost all Linux installation or live CDs) to see if it is your memory which causes problems. It might probably be a bad contact, so try to open your laptop and re-seat all removeable extensions (especially memory, WiFi card, etc.). While at it, clean it from dust which might get into the sockets.

If the problem persists, it might be related to some soldering joints becoming bad and there is relatively little you can do.

Comment: If nothing of the above helps then you might try this: Hacking, last resort, that might work - or kill it entirely: http://lifehacker.com/5823227/save-dying-video-cards-with-a-quick-bake-in-the-oven